# Comparing wifi SSID to a string in c++

Tags: android, c++, wifi

**I am trying to compare the WiFi SSID of the connected wifi to the one I want it to connect to. i'm using rad studio 10.2.3 c++. So I am using the following code**:

```
 _di_JObject obj = SharedActivityContext()->getApplicationContext()-> 
 getSystemService(TJContext::JavaClass->WIFI_SERVICE);
 _di_JWifiManager wifiMng = TJWifiManager::Wrap(((_di_ILocalObject)obj)-> 
 GetObjectID());

 _di_JWifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiMng->getConnectionInfo();

 String ssid = JStringToString(wifiInfo->getSSID()->toString());

 //ive also tried the below code with no success
 String ssid = wifiInfo->getSSID()->toString();

 if(JStringToString(wifiInfo->getSSID()->equals("\"HomeWifi\"")))
 {
    ShowMessage("Connected to: "+JStringToString(wifiInfo->getSSID()));
 }
 else
 {
    ShowMessage("Not connected to: "+JStringToString(wifiInfo->getSSID()));
 }
```

i get an error in the if statement.
Error: no viable conversion from 'const char [12]' to '_di_JString' (aka 'DelphiInterface')

please help...

Comment: I think you got a bracket in the wrong place somewhere in `if(JStringToString(wifiInfo->getSSID()->equals("\"HomeWifi\"")))` As coded you are trying to the output of `equals`, probably a boolean of some sort, with `JStringToString`.

Comment: `wifiInfo->getSSID()` -- This is repeated at least 4 times in the code you posted.  Why not save the value to a variable the first time and just use that variable?  It not only makes the program more readable, but also a good chance that your program runs (slightly) faster.

Comment: even if i call wifiInfo->getSSID() once i still get an error. the problem is in the IF statement and the bracket are correct i checked.

Comment: String ssid = JStringToString(wifiInfo->getSSID()->toString());

  if(wifiInfo->getSSID()->equals(ssid))// i still get an error

Comment: The error message isn't useful? Looks like `equals()` expects an object '_di_JString' and you are passing a string literal?

Comment: You get a different error. You have multiple bugs. You likely want something like `if(ssid->equals(String("\"HomeWifi\"")))`

Comment: if i do this :                                                                               
             if(wifiInfo->getSSID()->equals("\"HomeWifi\""))                            i get an erro: no viable conversion from 'const char [12]' to '_di_JObject' (aka DelphiInterface<Androidapi::Jni::Javatypes::JObject>')

Comment: i have changed my statement to, if(JStringToString(wifiInfo->getSSID()->toString()) == tmpSSID). this statement compiles with no errors but it doesn't go to the if statement. please help

Answer (score 0):

the solution to my problem is

```
if((JStringToString(wifiInfo->getSSID()->toString())) == "\"" + tmpSSID + "\"")
```